# How to redraw or update width/height of extjs grid after setSource() function is called?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, resize

I have main window which has inner grid components. When I press a button in the window, one of the grid components gets updated with data from database. That part is working well but when I resize the window component this grid component doesn't gets resized. It looks like it gets fixed width when setSource() is called.

Is there an extjs function that can redraw/update size of the grid component or how to preven this from happening?

I use this component Ext.grid.property.Grid from ext js 4

Here is the main container

```
var main_container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',
{
   xtype: 'container',
   id: "container_id",
   anchor: '100%',
   layout:'column',
   items:[
      column_1,
      column_2,
      column_3
   ]
})
```

Comment: Generally the function is container.doLayout() but normally it happens automatically. Are you using a layout? Post your component hierarchy or better the code (simplified) that creates your components.

Comment: Ok. I added structure of my container. Is this helpfull?

Comment: column 2 and 3 do not resize well. First coulmn gets data from db while rendering the window, so I guess thats why it doesn't make problems. While as other two columns get data after button click

Comment: So the problem is that the column inside your container doesn't get resized properly or the container itself doesn't resize? I don't think [columnLayout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column) supports dynamically changing width according to content inside them, they can just use a fixed percentage of container's width.

Comment: Yes the column inside don't get resized

Comment: Which other layout supports dinamic resizing of the component but is similar to column layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any layout that would allow you to dynamically resize columns to fit their contents, this is a non-trivial task (imagine how would you implement it on your own). 
You can specify a fixed percentage width to every column according to your expectations on the length of data inside it, something like:

```
 items: [{
        title: 'Column 1',
        columnWidth: .25
    },{
        title: 'Column 2',
        columnWidth: .55
    },{
        title: 'Column 3',
        columnWidth: .20
    }],
```

You can also give a fixed width to any column, this way the remaining space would be shared by percentage-width columns. Refer to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column

Otherwise you would have to measure every cell's width after each data update to figure out a cell with maximum width and attempt to resize column according to that width (but still make sure the total width of all columns doesn't exceed container width).